# Is it possible to create a circuit that switches from external power (DC) to a battery once it's fully charged?

Tags: power-supply, solar-energy

I was wondering if it is possible to create a circuit that primarily uses external power from an outlet, but will switch to a battery once it gains charge.

The battery would be lithium-ion and would be charged using a solar panel. Since the energy created from the solar panel would be very low, I can't use the battery consistently. How should I go about making a circuit that switches to battery power once the battery is over 50% charged and then flips back after it reaches 25% charge?

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't use the solar panel and/or wall power to charge the battery until it's 100% charged and only use the battery when neither source is available?  Also please share the specifications of the wall power source, solar panel, battery, and circuit you're powering.

Comment: `is it possible?` question almost always has a `yes` answer

Comment: Aarin, I'm not sure about what you are writing. You say you cannot use the battery *consistently* because the solar panel *energy* is *very low*. (I think you mean *power*.) This implies that the solar panel is insufficient. How would you imagine that when the battery declines down to 25% and you switch to solar power that the battery would then charge back to 50% again? It seems to me that you'd need to shut everything off until the solar panel can charge the battery back to 50% but that you certainly could not be running your device then. What am I missing?

Comment: @jonk - "primarily uses external power from an outlet", not from the solar panel (which is apparently only used to charge the battery).

Answer (score 0):

As already written in the comments, if the Question is "is it possible" the answer is almost always "yes".

So from your question I assume that mains is just the backup when the solar panel does not deliver enough energy and the battery does not have enough charge. And you're not charging your battery from mains but only from the solar panel.

**Simple, analog solution**
In a very simple case you measure the cell voltage of your battery to get the charge level. And use this voltage to switch to either mains or battery. This can be done with a comparator with hysteresis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBKMTq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is just a circuit to give you a general idea of how this might look.

I'd suggest you use a battery with a BMS, an MPPT charging controler to optimally use the energy from the solar panel and use a microcontroler to get the data from the BMS and do the switching.

Keep in mind that batteries age with charging. Depending on the chemistry, the lifespan can be extended by selecting a good usage pattern. In general: most batteries don't like to be deep discharged. Some batteries are destroyed ba deep discharge, others just "don't like it". Take care to avoid deep descharges.

And while NiCad (and also NiMH to some extent) as well as Lead Acid batteries don't mind to be overcharged with small currents, most chemistries that include lithium don't tolerate that (some even thend to start fires out of protest).

So research well what usage pattern your battery "likes" and select the parameters of your system according to that.

Answer (score 0):

This question is asked all to often, and people miss the fact that it's a solution in search of a problem. In most applications there is no need to switch. The simplest solution works well and indeed is used in every cell-phone tower base station.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPDtDj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At any given time:

- If the load is using less current than the charger can put out, the battery will charge
- If the load is using exactly as much current as the charger can put out, the battery current is 0 (the battery neither charges nor discharges)
- If the load requires more current than the charger can provide, the battery will discharge

In other words, the battery current will be equal to the difference between the load current and the charger current.

```
battery current = load current - charger current
```